# Kalman Filter initial Q values

Tags: kalman-filters

I have a 6 state Kalman Filter (Unscented).

When I use a diagonal matrix only for Q (i.e only the diagonal has covariances), I get a "smooth" plot of estimate against actual.

If I use the entire Q matrix (i.e include all covariances) I get an estimate that oscillates around actual wildly.

Is it incorrect to just use diagonal?

ADDITIONAL:

I am using 6 correlated Equity Stocks Price timeseries. In constructing the covariance matrix I use the difference between consecutive prices. I do NOT log the data.

Comment: Are the state process noises correlated? If the "true" system has them correlated, then you should use the off-diagonal entries.  If you don't know, just use the diagonal entries.

Comment: Yes - they are correlated - they are all Equity Price time series. Using the full matrix makes the Kalman unusable - what might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you copy paste the matrices?

Comment: [This question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/21796/question-about-q-matrix-noise-process-covariance-in-kalman-filter) and the [book that the (broken) links go to](https://github.com/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python/blob/master/08-Designing-Kalman-Filters.ipynb)  may be of some interest.

Comment: Yes - I had already seen those. But it's nice to talk to someone with personal experience. I am now wondering if I should weight all "off diagonal" values by some constant - perhaps that would make the estimate less jumpy. Or maybe I should have used log difference etc.

Comment: Compare the eigen values. And make sure it's "big" enough

Comment: If I only use a diagonal matrix, it appears that other states do NOT effect the estimate of the first state. Is that correct?